# Are adult negativity or resentment related to an infant crying for attention?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, emotion, developmental-psychology, behavior

I've recently came across an idea, expressed by a spiritual author Ekhart Tolle, that for adults, the internal experience of negativity or resistance to life situations can be far more harmful than the situation itself. Typically a person cannot take immediate action to resolve such situation.

For example, a loud car alarm outside interrupts some activity. A person may become focused on how inconvenient it is to hear this alarm, and start thinking negative thoughts, like `"I can't believe that jerk has such a loud alarm on that a piece of junk car. Who would steal such a thing? I wish someone would put a brick though his windshield".`

This got me thinking - **What is the process by which negativity or resentment to situations arise in a person?** The scenario of a crying infant came to mind - a baby cries to express some discomfort and frustration at a situation that the baby cannot fix himself. **Are adult resentment and infant crying using the same pathways in the brain?**